# Python numpy questions: Why does np.all not evaluate to True when given a 2D numpy array populated with NaN (not a number)?

Tags: python, numpy

I've been experimenting with np.all in Python. I've looked at the documentation here:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html

I'm expecting the np.all statements below to evaluate to: [True, True, True] and True but they don't.

What am I missing here?

I've tried the code below:

```
import numpy as np

NA = float("NAN")
arrNA = np.array([[NA, NA, NA], [NA, NA, NA], [NA, NA, NA]])

print(np.all(arrNA == NA, axis=0)) 
#This prints [False, False, False], but every element in the np.array is equal to NA. Why not True?

print(np.all(arr == NA)) 
#This also prints false, but every element in the np.array is NA. Why not True?
```

Comment: Have you every tried `print(NaN == NaN)`? It might help you understand what's going on.

Comment: Contrast your examples with `print(np.all(arrNA))` which *does* give `True`. This is what the documentation is getting at when it says that "NaN (etc) evaluate to True". That's different to comparing two NaNs to each other, like @BRemelzwaal said.

Comment: `NaN == NaN` is `False` by definition. Moreover, `NaN` is _never_ equal to anything. That's why the results are all `False`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. This helped me out. I found a way to do the evaluation I am trying to do with: np.all(np.isnan(arrNA))

Answer (score 1):

According to the IEEE floating point standard, NaN is not equal to itself:

```py
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
```

So when you write `arrNA == NA`, you get a boolean array where every element is `False`.

If you want to check for the presence of NaN values, you can use `np.isnan`:

```py
>>> np.all(np.isnan(arrNA))
True
```